# Im getting "Error: Maximum update depth exceeded" when reloading my reactJS project

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting Error: *Maximum update depth exceeded* after reloading my react project. I'm making a dynamic table, where the number of columns change depending on the data from a JSON file. It seems like the error only happens in this line of code

```
const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, []);
const columns = Object.keys(data[1]).map((key, id) => {
  return {
    Header: key,
    accessor: key
  };
});
```

This is the whole js file

```
export const DisplayTable = () => {
  const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, []);
  const columns = Object.keys(data[1]).map((key, id) => {
    return {
      Header: key,
      accessor: key
    };
  });

  console.log(columns);

  const tableInstance = useTable({
    columns,
    data
  });

  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow
  } = tableInstance;

  return (
    <table {...getTableProps()}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>
      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row) => {
          prepareRow(row);
          return (
            <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `react-table`, please make sure:

The columns also need `memoized`, so you need to wrap in a useMemo like the data. [docs](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#instance-properties)

```js
    const columns = useMemo(
      () => Object.keys(data[1])
      .map((key, id)=>{
        return {
          Header: key,
          accessor: key
        }
      }, [data])
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately the error still occurs when I reload the page. Accessing the page for the first time is fine, all the data displays on the table. I tried to print the data on the console and when I reload, it seems like the component is being called over and over again.